# MySQL - will indexes speed up my search queries?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, search, indexing

I have a table for patients in a hospital, so potentially over time this table could contain tens of thousands of rows. A hospital-unique ID number (BIGINT) is assigned to each patient which serves as the PRIMARY KEY, and the rest of the columns are VARCHAR or CHAR, and a single DATE column. As far as I know, PRIMARY KEYS are automatically indexed so searching by the patient's ID is optimal(?).

Patients can be searched by a single field or a combination of this ID, name, address, date of birth etc. Can I optimize my search simply by creating an INDEX on each one of these fields? Would this optimization also work when a search is performed on a combination of these INDEXed fields such as

```
 SELECT * FROM patients WHERE first_name="John" AND address="blah blah blah";
```

???

Also, I presume MySQL uses its own internal algorithms for searching, perhaps binary search, and users cannot choose or implement their own?

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html which is a pretty interesting read anyway:

> Suppose that you issue the following SELECT statement:
>
> mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> If a multiple-column index exists on col1 and col2, the appropriate rows
>   can be fetched directly. If separate single-column indexes exist on
>   col1 and col2, the optimizer will attempt to use the Index Merge
>   optimization (see

Comment: Would there be a disadvantage to creating both single and multi-column indexes for all combinations of the columns for searching? For example, I could have an index on first_name, a separate index on address, another index on first_name AND address, and so on...

Comment: Indexes take up space. Why don't you just try it and see if you like it. You can delete indexes too, if they don't help.